# Function preg_match() is not finding the end of line appropriately

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm parsing through information in a file coming from a console, at the end of each line is the date, but the line may also have the date already listed in it. The input lines look like this:

```
 00029 --> Ticket Received in QUEUE11 by ABCDE on 04/11/2013 at 11:   4/11/2013 
 00030 07:12.                                                         4/11/2013
```

(There's a space before each line number and at the end of the line).

My regex in my `foreach` loop looks like this:

```
if (preg_match("/\s\d{5}\s(.+?)\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}\s\n/", $line, $match))
{
    $note = $match[1];
}
```

The regex is working in *The Regex Coach* and I can't find any reason why it won't work in my code. With the \n there, it matches no line. Without it, it cuts off before the first date.

I also tried \r and it behaves the same as having nothing. I'm looking for the final output to look like this once I've echoed $note in the loop.

```
Ticket Received in QUEUE11 by ABCDE on 04/11/2013 at 11:
07:12.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I first used \n which didn't work which is why I tried $, since $ is for multiline, I've edited the post for the \n

Comment: It doesn't match up how you expect, because `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}` gets the _first_ date in the line, ie before `at 11`, so asserting the end of the string there will cause it to fail.

Comment: I knew it was something simple, yes, replacing .+? with .+ fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make the spaces at the end optional:

```
if (preg_match("/\s\d{5}\s(.+?)\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}\s*\n/", $line, $match))
//                                                here ___^
{
    $note = $match[1];
}
```